# How to get a user from local AD using ldap3?

Tags: python, ldap, python-ldap, ldap3

I am trying to get a particular user from AD using the ldap3 python module. Here is how I am trying to do it:

```
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, ALL

srv = Server('company.com', get_info=ALL)
conn = Connection(srv)
if conn.bind():

    user = 'John'


    results = conn.search('ou=Users,ou=Office1,ou=HQ,dc=company,dc=com',
                      "(&(objectClass=person)(givenName=" + user + "))", attributes=['mail', 
                      'sn', 'givenName'])

    print(results)

else:
     print('not connection')
```

This code results in False being printed on the terminal.
I can't get where I am doing it wrong.

Comment: Could it be that you're not addressing the search result? https://ldap3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/connection.html#result If I understand this documentation, the `connection.search()` updates the `connection.result` attribute with the latest search result status, and `connection.response` stores the response.

Comment: As shown here: https://ldap3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial_searches.html I was expecting that conn.search() will return True and I will be able to access the search results using conn.entries

Comment: I'm afraid I can't deduce what the issue might be. You successfully bind to the LDAP server but find no results. Just as a sanity check, are you certain the user you're searching for exists?

Comment: Yeah I am sure the user is there, in fact I am using my own account/givenname.

Comment: Could it be because of Anonymous Binding that I am using now?

Comment: Even if this question is old, you should have given the result of the command `ldapsearch` for the same request. The command `ldapsearch` would have helped you (and us) to find what could be the issue.